# Slow performance of query doing a clustered index seek vs scan

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

For some reason, the second query below runs SIGNIFICANTLY slower than the first, even though it is doing an index seek on the clustered key.

Database size: 
Data - 20GB (only 15gb used)
Log - 20GB (only 700mb used)

Partitions - 186 (partitioned by the ENdTransDateTime column)

If the EndTransDateTime filter is removed from the query, the optimiser performs an index scan and the query returns in a matter of seconds (as opposed to minutes).

FYI - I have absolutely no control over the queries as these are generated by an application. This is apparently consistent behaviour - if a date filer is applied, the query runs for ages. Soon as removed, it executes in seconds. I ave been given some examples to work with. Below is only 1 example:

-- This query takes around 2.2 mins to execute

```
 SELECT TOP 1000  [t5].[StoreNo] AS [Store_No], [t5].[Name] AS [Store_Name], [t5].[CashierNo] AS [Cashier_No], [t5].[TradingDay] AS [Trading_Day], [t5].[value] AS [Unique_Count_of_Results], [t5].[value2] AS [Count_of_Results]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t4].[StoreNo], [t4].[Name], [t4].[CashierNo], [t4].[TradingDay], [t4].[value], [t4].[value2]
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT [t0].[TransactionID]) AS [value], COUNT_BIG(*) AS [value2], [t0].[StoreNo], [t3].[Name], [t0].[CashierNo], [t0].[TradingDay]
        FROM [CRDMPointOfSale].[dbo].[CRDM_Header] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [CRDMPointOfSale].[dbo].[CRDM_Item] AS [t1] ON [t0].[TransactionID] = [t1].[TransactionID]
        INNER JOIN [CRDMPointOfSale].[dbo].[CRDM_Tender] AS [t2] ON [t1].[TransactionID] = [t2].[TransactionID]
        INNER JOIN [GAME_ReferenceData].[dbo].[Ref_LocationHierarchy] AS [t3] ON [t2].[StoreNo] = [t3].[StoreNo]
        WHERE ([t0].[TicketAmount] < 0) AND (([t1].[ReturnType] = 2) OR ([t1].[ReturnType] = 1) OR ([t1].[ReturnType] = 21)) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] = 1) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 2) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 8) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 4) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 3) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 13) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 12) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 11) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 6) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 7) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 99) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 14) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 5) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 9) AND (NOT ([t1].[WasCanceledFlg] = 1)) AND (NOT ([t1].[CancelFlg] = 1)) 
        AND ([t0].[EndTransDateTime] > '20180418 23:59:59') AND ([t0].[EndTransDateTime] < '20180613 23:59:59') 
        AND ([t0].[StoreNo] <> 889)
        GROUP BY [t0].[StoreNo], [t3].[Name], [t0].[CashierNo], [t0].[TradingDay]
        ) AS [t4]
    ) AS [t5]
ORDER BY [t5].[value] DESC
```

-- This query takes around 2 seconds
-- The only change is commenting out the EndTransDateTime filters in the WHERE clause

```
 SELECT TOP 1000  [t5].[StoreNo] AS [Store_No], [t5].[Name] AS [Store_Name], [t5].[CashierNo] AS [Cashier_No], [t5].[TradingDay] AS [Trading_Day], [t5].[value] AS [Unique_Count_of_Results], [t5].[value2] AS [Count_of_Results]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t4].[StoreNo], [t4].[Name], [t4].[CashierNo], [t4].[TradingDay], [t4].[value], [t4].[value2]
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT [t0].[TransactionID]) AS [value], COUNT_BIG(*) AS [value2], [t0].[StoreNo], [t3].[Name], [t0].[CashierNo], [t0].[TradingDay]
        FROM [CRDMPointOfSale].[dbo].[CRDM_Header] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [CRDMPointOfSale].[dbo].[CRDM_Item] AS [t1] ON [t0].[TransactionID] = [t1].[TransactionID]
        INNER JOIN [CRDMPointOfSale].[dbo].[CRDM_Tender] AS [t2] ON [t1].[TransactionID] = [t2].[TransactionID]
        INNER JOIN [GAME_ReferenceData].[dbo].[Ref_LocationHierarchy] AS [t3] ON [t2].[StoreNo] = [t3].[StoreNo]
        WHERE ([t0].[TicketAmount] < 0) AND (([t1].[ReturnType] = 2) OR ([t1].[ReturnType] = 1) OR ([t1].[ReturnType] = 21)) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] = 1) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 2) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 8) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 4) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 3) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 13) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 12) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 11) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 6) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 7) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 99) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 14) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 5) AND ([t2].[MediaNo] <> 9) AND (NOT ([t1].[WasCanceledFlg] = 1)) AND (NOT ([t1].[CancelFlg] = 1)) 
        --AND ([t0].[EndTransDateTime] > '20180418 23:59:59') AND ([t0].[EndTransDateTime] < '20180613 23:59:59') 
        AND ([t0].[StoreNo] <> 889)
        GROUP BY [t0].[StoreNo], [t3].[Name], [t0].[CashierNo], [t0].[TradingDay]
        ) AS [t4]
    ) AS [t5]
ORDER BY [t5].[value] DESC
```

I have the execution plans for both, but am not sure how to upload them? Any way I can do this? (tried ding in a code block but the xml document is too large)

Once I have loaded the execution plans, I would appreciate some advice as to how to troubleshoot what the issue is. I have already run an UPDATE stats for the tables in teh query.

We have a number of clients on an identical set up with TB's of data with no issues of performance. I have no idea as to where to look/what to do etc to try and understand what is happening here.

Thank you

Here are some screen shots of the 2 clustered index seeks in question (39% each of the long running query). Ironically, the EndTransDateTIme filter referenced is on the 'CRDM_Header' table.

[image]

Here are the query plans (what an awesome utility):
2 second query: 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1VmIj1bm

2.2minute query: 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ5FLsJWQ

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (<sql-server>?)

Comment: Use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to upload the plans for SQL Server.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2016

Comment: THank you EzLo - I will post shortly on my return

Comment: Query plans added above :)

Comment: How long does running just the innermost query take with the filter?

Comment: Also have you updated stats on CRDM_Header'? There seems to be a large difference between estimated and actual rows in the plan.

Comment: Well, that's a bit embarrassing. I just ran both queries, and now results return in seconds. Its been like this for weeks so I have no idea why this has suddenly been resolved. There is a nightly process that updates stats using sp_updatestats. But I have read that is unreliable. Anyway, thank you to those who took the time to answer my call. It is much appreciated!!